# AJAX post data is null in c# controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I don't know why I'm having this problem.

I already tried the answered found here in stackoverflow but the value received in the controller is still null.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("PayNow")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PayNow([FromBody] CompleteOrderInfo request)
        {
            
            return View();
        }
```

And this is the model

```
public class CompleteOrderInfo
    {
        
        public string TCO { get; set; }
        public string OrderNo { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public string PayRef1 { get; set; }

    }
```

And this is the screenshot of the debugging which the model **CompleteOrderInfo** has a value

[image]

And this is the javascript code

```
var CompleteOrderInfo = {};
            CompleteOrderInfo.TCO = tco;
            CompleteOrderInfo.OrderNo = orderNo;
            CompleteOrderInfo.Amount = totalPrice;
            CompleteOrderInfo.PayRef1 = $('#remarks').val();
            var textboxvalue = $('#remarks').val();
            console.log(textboxvalue);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Orders/PayNow",
                data: JSON.stringify(CompleteOrderInfo),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        toastr.success(data.message);
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(data.message);
                    }
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    //console.log('failed');
                    //alert(response.d);
                    toastr.error(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    toastr.error(response.d);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hello,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ajax code

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Orders/PayNow",
                data: { request:CompleteOrderInfo },
             
                success: function (result) {
                   
                alert(JSON.strigfy(result));
                   
                },
               
                error: function (response) {
                    toastr.error(response.d);
                }
            });
```

and change the action for debugging, remove [FromBody]

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PayNow(CompleteOrderInfo request)
        {
            
            return Ok("success");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type of `Amount` is `decimal`,but your `CompleteOrderInfo.Amount` in ajax is `string` type.So you need to convert it to `int` type.Change

```
CompleteOrderInfo.Amount = totalPrice;
```

to

```
CompleteOrderInfo.Amount = parseInt(totalPrice);
```